# Services to purchase on Azure to host html 5 and flash files

Tags: azure, hosting, server

I need a public facing hosting server that I can ftp virtual tour files that include html 5, flash, xml, type files.

I'm a little confused by Azure's offering.  Do I need to fire up a virtual server?  Or is there an app that can make this happen?

I'm assuming from what I know, I need a server whether it be a .net or linux stack.  If I fire up a virtual server, can you give me a basic config I'll need?

I currently build wordpress sites, but for this particular one, I'm creating a sub-domain and simply hosting virtual tours.  Not running a wordpress site on this, just simply need a bucket to show my virtual tours.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this type of question doesn't fit here; there's no single right way to host your website in Azure, and there are many ways to do what you're looking to do. As this isn't a discussion forum, it's not the place to post answer for each of these ways. And what you're asking is about the general service offering, which is all spelled out at azure.com (including an entire area of [documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/), including info on vm's, services such as websites, stateless cloud services, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Azure Websites offer FTP access. I would start there.